# POST multiple collections

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a method like this (the parameters name intentionally stupid for this example):

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("rest/myMethod")]
        public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(string param1, DateTime param2, DateTime param3, IEnumerable<string> param4, IEnumerable<string> param5 = null)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

But when I test it in Swagger I get this error:

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('param4' and 'param5') to the request's content.",
  "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "stackTrace": ""
}
```

As soon as I remove one of the two collection parameter this works fine.

Why is that ? How can I POST multiple collections of objects in my WebApi ?

Thanks.

PS: I don't know if this is a usefull piece of intelligence but this WebApi will be called from a AngularJS client.

Comment: Try to pass IEnumerable in POST body,(in JSON format) not URL. Use [FromBody] and it schould bind it correctlu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I POST multiple collections of objects in my WebApi ?

By wrapping them in a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Param2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Param3 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Param4 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Param5 { get; set; }
}
```

that your POST action will take as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/myMethod")]
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Now you could have the following request:

```
POST /rest/myMethod HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 174
Connection: close

{
    "Param1": "value of param1",
    "Param2": "2017-01-18T07:31:02Z",
    "Param3": "2017-01-19T07:31:02Z",
    "Param4": [ "foo", "bar" ],
    "Param5": [ "baz" ]
}
```

Comment: This works fine but why is my first solution not working ?

Comment: Because you can have only 1 parameter that comes from the body of a POST request. This is by design.

Comment: Ok, but when there is only the 4 first parameters this works. This mean that the 3 first parameters are not in the body. How it is decided whether a parameter goes in the body or not ?